# REST API custom MatchError handling elegantly

Tags: rest, api, elixir

I'm working on a REST API in Elixir. I'm trying to design a system that allows me to fail pattern matching with a custom message to be returned to the client. I'm using Plug.

Let's say I have an endpoint for creating a user in my database, I might make the following statement to fail if an account already exists:
`0 = DbAdapter.select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'email@example.com';)`

This fails with a `MatchError` and plug returns a generic `Internal server error` to the client.

What I'd like to do, is define some construct like the following:

`0 = DbAdapter.select("...") << %{code: 1113, reason: "account already exists"}`

Basically, if the assertion `0 = DbAdapter.select("...")` fails, I'd like to return `%{code: 1113, reason: "account already exists"}` to the client. My goal is really easy syntax, like the syntax above (maybe operator overloading or something).

My understanding is that plug handles errors in the following method:

```
def handle_errors(conn, ree = %{kind: _kind, reason: _reason, stack: _stack}) do
    IO.inspect ree
    send_resp(conn, conn.status, "Internal error: The resource you're looking for might not exist on the server.")
end
```

How can I get a custom error tuple on assertion failure, and return it to the client in handle_errors?
Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using phoenix for this?

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari Doesn't support the database I'm using as well as I'd like, as well as a few other things, my server doesn't need all the features it does. I actually did figure out a system that is working alright by using Plug's built in error system, so that's not to bad, just requires a little more syntax than what would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

`handle_errors` is used to handle errors that may happen with your request, not a special kind of status to return depending on the result of an action.

What you need is to create your application to either return valid data, or a meaningful error code from which it will generate the appropriate response for the client:

```
case DbAdapter.select("...") do
  0 -> create!
  _ -> %{code: 1113, reason: "account already exists"}
end
```

And somewhere else, maybe perhaps in another Plug:

```
case data do
  %{code: 1113, reason: reason} -> send_resp(conn, 418, reason)
  %{code: 200, data: data} -> send_resp(conn, 200, data)
end
```